# Upload image and mp3 in same form, but mp3 did not get uploaded

Tags: php

i'm trying upload image and mp3 in the same form but image is uploaded and mp3 is not.
this is my form

```
 <form action="upload.php"
 enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <p>
 Please select image<br>
 <input type="file" name="image" size="40">
 </p>
 <p>
 Please select audio<br>
 <input type="file" name="audio" size="40">
 </p>
```

and this is my upload.php

```
// checking image
if (($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
or ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
or ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
or ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
{
    if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] == 0)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
        "upload/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]);

    }
    else
    {
        echo "image upload failed";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "file is not supported image";

}

// checking mp3
if (substr($_FILES["audio"]["name"],-3) == "mp3")
{
    if ($_FILES["audio"]["error"] == 0)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["audio"]["tmp_name"],
        "upload/".$_FILES["audio"]["name"]);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "audio upload failed";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "file is not supported audio";

}
```

now, image get's uploaded and moved to ./upload but on mp3 it echoes "audio upload failed".
Don't get it

Comment: You should do a basic var_dump to check what is the error code being returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code correct for your work just check your 
upload_max_filesize on your php.ini 
default upload size limit 2mb chage it.

Comment: yes, that was it. I thought I changed that but that was on server php.ini, not on computer, tnx

Comment: if you cant edit php.ini just write on your php file header this line ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "16M");

Answer (score 6):

Try echo `$_FILES["audio"]["error"]` value and see the number of error. Zero means that there is no error. In your case some error occurs. Here you can get the meaning of error number http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

It is bad practice to compare to zero

```
if ($_FILES["audio"]["error"] == 0)
```

You should use the constant:

```
if ($_FILES["audio"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
```

But it is just the best practice. It does not influence the result of the code.